# Group by incompatible google sql cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I did an experiment to create multiple queries on Google SQL cloud, as shown in the picture, but the result is

> ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression # 5 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY
>   clause and contains nonaggregated column 'ipol.sales.name' which is
>   not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode = only_full_group_by

[image: please help solution, thank you]

Answer (score 7):

In cloud SQL instance go to Edit option and Add Database Flag SQL mode - Traditional
[image: Add Database Flag SQL mode - Traditional]

Answer (score 2):

if you run this query in your database

```
select version(),@@sql_mode;
```

you will get

| version() | @@sql_mode |
| --- | --- |
| 8.0.26-google | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |

the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in the `@@sql_mode` caused the problem.

edit your Cloud SQL via GCP GUI page

add flag `sql_mode`, select all of the value in the `@@sql_mode` except `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` and save.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot `SET GLOBAL` unless you're logged in as `root` (or equivalent) user.

and also, the `GROUP BY` clause is invalid. fix the statement before running it

... whatever `Expression # 5` may be (just count them).

this comes from `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`.

Comment: so what is the solution to be able to query this group by

Comment: @gagahgelap just don't use SQL mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` ...and if you cannot set that `GLOBAL`, try setting it for `SESSION` - or group differently. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html